# R pie chart, set legend pch as numbers

Tags: r, legend

As the chart shows:

[image]

The legend code is as follows:

```
legend ("right", legend=c(csv$Strain),col="black", 
        pch=paste(seq_len(nrow(csv))), cex=1, pt.cex=1.5, lwd=2,lty=0)
```

Because the labels are overlapped and the label names are too long, so I wanted to display the label names in legend with number pch. But I found that the pch will only display the first left digit, ideally it should be from **1 - 25**.

Anybody know how to do this? or may have better solutions for this?

Thanks very much.

**=========== update ============**

This is the datasheet I used:

[image]

I actually don't have to use numbers (1-25) as the chart labels or the legend pch, but I was trying to find a way to represent above datasheet by using pie chart.

Comment: A bar chart, perhaps?

Comment: I have tried the bar chart, but I also wanted to find out about how to do the legend part.

Comment: Can you post a `dput` of the data frame for this? (or, at least the salient columns for it?)

Comment: change the cex parameter

Comment: As an aside, this data looks like a great example of when pie charts fail. [https://blogs.oracle.com/experience/entry/countdown_of_top_10_reasons_to_never_ever_use_a_pie_chart]

Comment: changing the cex for both pch and text are still getting the same result.